# ASP.net "generic" SOAP web services

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I've developed a data access layer that grants the following methods to any subclasses:

```
List<DataObject> Select(int primaryKey)
List<DataObject> SelectAll()
void Insert(...)
void Delete(int primaryKey)
void Update(...)
```

I'd like for there to be some easy way I can wire them up to some kind of dispatcher that would look at the URL, pick out the type and present the CRUD operations as web methods in a traditional SOAP web service, generating the WSDL for them on the fly.

Something like:

http://Server/Customer/
or
http://Server/Address/

That would present the typical web service client test page we're all used to seeing, with `Select()`, etc presented as Web Methods. Is that possible in ASP.net? How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use ASMX web services for new development. Use WCF instead.

In your particular case, see [ADO.NET Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106.aspx) (renamed to WCF Data Services in .NET 4.0).